# Identifying whether a PCI device is PCI or PCIe

Tags: c++, pci, pci-e

I need to be able to identify whether a given PCI device is express or non-express at runtime. One possible way to ID this is to get the Configuration space and check for an extended section. If the extended section exists then it's a PCIe card. Specifically i would check the first four bytes to see if they are `0x100` as the specification requires.

Is this the best way to validate what type of card is being used? Are my assumptions correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way is to look for the PCI Express capability, which is in the regular capability space, not the extended space. The presence of this capability indicates a PCIe device. The capability ID is 0x10.

Comment: where in the configuration space is the pcie capability ID? What's the offset?

Comment: It’s somewhere in the capability list. You have to search for it starting at the beginning of the capability list.

Comment: Is the capability ID a reflection of the hardware or software?